# CSS div-table and text-overflow:ellipsis

Tags: css, layout

I have a div with a display of table. I want for this table to take up 100% of the page. Within the table will be one row with several cells (display style of table-cell). My goal is for a CSS solution that allows the table-cells to show an ellipsis if the text is too long. I have put together a simple example jsFIddle that shows the issue.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to get the cells to show the ellipsis?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/311chaos/uDqzP/3/)

```
<div class="table-wrap-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
       <div class="table-row">
           <div class="table-cell data">
               <span>This_is_a_really_long_username_that_is_too_long</span>
           </div>
           <div class="table-cell">
           </div>   
           <div class="table-cell data">
                <span>This_is_a_really_long_emailAddress_that_is_too_long</span>
           </div>
           <div class="table-cell">
           </div>   
           <div class="table-cell data">
                <span>This_is_a_really_long_string_that_is_too_long</span>
           </div>     
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use max-width on .table-cell to fix it:

```
.table-cell {     
    max-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/uDqzP/10/

Comment: but then its only 50px wide, rather than spanning the 100%...I want it to take up as much room as it is able, then the overflow goes to the ellipsis.

Comment: You're going to need to define widths somewhere (unless you want to use JavaScript).

Comment: @AaronHickman: max-width: 100% on the `.table-cell` would do just that: make `.table-cell` its full width. You don't want that being you're trying to make ellipses work.

Comment: Thanks, that does appear to do what I want! 
http://jsfiddle.net/311chaos/uDqzP/11/